# Traefik IngressRoute is ignoring TLS secret

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s, cert-manager, traefik-ingress

We have newly built a K3S Cluster with Rancher, Cert-Manager, Longhorn and Traefix Ingress with external HAProxy LB & Keep-Alive.

The only issue is when trying to use TLS via Global Sign wildcard certificate, Traefik is ignoring our commercially purchase certificate and using it own self sign certificate, I have spent days trailing the internet for a solution with no luck.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

I am not able to get cert-manage to provide LE cert via HTTP-01, it's always in pending state, yet if I use verification url I do receive back the a valid matching.

Although I have read that Traefix does not like *.domain.com, I also combine root.crt, intermediate cert, key into .pem and created secret with combine pem for both key & crt. But this no join.